# Top half of text in pygame is not being displayed

Tags: python, pygame

I imported a custom font called "Celtic-Bit Thin" from a website to use in a project. The file had the correct extension (.ttf) that pygame can import but when used, only the bottom half of the string of text that is displayed is shown (You can only see the bottom half of each letter in the string of text displayed in the font I chose). I'm not sure if it is a problem with the font or the way I implemented it. I tried:

```
gameFont = pygame.font.Sysfont("Celtic-Bit Thin", 24)
font.render("Hello world!", False, (0,0,0))
```

I also tried doing it with `pygame.font.Font()`but it didn't work either. Is the font simply incompatible with pygame or is there some other requirement for importing fonts?

EDIT: Here is a minimal, runnable example:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

gameFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Celtic-Bit Thin", 36)

running =  True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runnung = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(gameFont.render("Hello World!",False,(0,0,0)), (300, 300))
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

AND [here](https://all-free-download.com/font/download/celtic_bit_13716.html) is where I downloaded the font

Comment: Please post a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There you go. I hope you can help

Comment: Did you test it out?

Comment: The font is cut off, but as far as I can see the code should work correctly. I've got no idea what is causing this problem.

Comment: Glad you could try

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the font is cut off, but I've tried to render it with the [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) module instead of `pygame.font` and that works fine.

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype  # Import the freetype module.


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
gameFont = pygame.freetype.SysFont("Celtic-Bit Thin", 24)
running =  True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    # You can use `render` ...
    text_surface, rect = gameFont.render("Hello World!", (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(text_surface, (40, 250))
    # or `render_to`.
    gameFont.render_to(screen, (40, 350), "Hello World!", (0,0,0))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do I need to use render and render_to like you did in the code? or do I only use one of them?

Comment: Only one of them.

Comment: what does `txt, rect` mean? I know that `font.render()` is stored in txt but what about the rect variable?

Comment: Also, why does the code work without having to initialize the pygame.freetype module?

Comment: [pygame.freetype.Font.render](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render) returns a tuple consisting of the text surface and the bounding rect. I unpack the tuple into the variables `txt` and  `rect` (look up "tuple unpacking" or "iterable unpacking"). -- `pygame.init()` initializes all pygame modules.

Comment: Final question. What do you think is a better choice to use, render and blit or render_to without blitting?

Comment: If the text never changes, I'd render it once ahead of the loop with `render`, otherwise I'd just use `render_to` in the loop.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if I wanted to add NPC's and textboxes, I should use `render_to`?

Comment: You really know a lot about python and pygame. How did you come to know so much about the language and how to use it with pygame?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181361/discussion-between-mohamed-ibrahim-student-and-skrx).